# Splitting collection of objects based on object property and threshold

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I need to split my list of objects into n list based on one of the objects property 
the property could be a list of links in this case.It should be split in such way that total number of links of elements in each output list should not be more than some threshold value e.g 10
my object class is as follow

```
Class MenuSectionData
{
  string description
  List<string> links
 }
```

The following list has number of objects from MenuSectionData class ,each of which has a specific number of  links e.g 2,3,4,1,2 .  In addition if number of link for one object is more than threshold ,basically I have to truncate the extra links according to available slot in each list

> Private menuSectionsDataList As List(Of
>   MenuSectionDate)=quickMenuDataHandler.GetData()

basically the output should be something like

```
List(Of List(Of MenuSectionData))
```

In a way that total number of link for each sub list of above list should not be more than 10 and could have maximum number of links it can holds according to input collection

Any sample to achieve this task is highly appreciated
 either in vb or C# using linq or others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work on Linqpad.

In the code below we specify we want a max of 10 links per section, and a max of 12 links in the list of sections.

```
void Main()
{
    var firstMenuSection = new MenuSectionData{
        Description = "First",
        Links = new List<string> {"link 1", "link 2", "link 3", "link 4","link 5", "link 6","link 7", "link 8","link 9", "link 10","link 11", "link 12"}};

    var secondMenuSection = new MenuSectionData{
        Description = "Second",
        Links = new List<string> {"link 1", "link 2", "link 3", "link 4","link 5"}};

    var initialMenu = new List<MenuSectionData>{
        firstMenuSection, secondMenuSection
    };

    var menu = CreateConstrainedMenu(initialMenu, 12, 10);

    menu.Dump();
}

public List<MenuSectionData> CreateConstrainedMenu(List<MenuSectionData> initialMenu, int maxNumberOfLinks, int maxNumberOfLinksPerSection){

    int remainingLinks = maxNumberOfLinks;
    foreach(var section in initialMenu){ 
        var availableLinks = section.Links.Take(Math.Min(remainingLinks,maxNumberOfLinksPerSection)).ToList();  
        section.Links = availableLinks;
        remainingLinks -=  availableLinks.Count();
    }

    return initialMenu;
}

public class MenuSectionData
{
  public  string Description {get;set;}
  public List<string> Links {get;set;}
 }  

// Define other methods and classes here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I dont have enough reputation to vote it up